# Audio Synthesis algorithms

Tags: sound, electronic-music, live-sound, modulation

I am little more than a starter in Sound synthesis using oscillators and others. I have reaktor 6 as a modular environment. I wanted to get nice algorightms from where i can get deeply started off. I see that people make their own synths and i want to get to that stage.

I searched on amazon for some books but could not find. Basically i wanted some learning material where i could get started nicely. Please quote.

Thanks,
Abhijeet.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Do you intend to write code to implement the actual math involved in creating basic waveforms?  E.g. [Subtractive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_synthesis) or [FM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation_synthesis) synthesis?

Comment: I wanted some standard material like some sites of universities or courses where these things are being taught...

Comment: Yes but *what things*? Do you want to learn actual algorithms so you can code to spec?  Or do you want to learn concepts so you can purchase software plugins? These would require very different answers.

Comment: I am using reaktor! So I want to learn algorithms for making particular kinds of sounds and also want to try new things simply speaking sound design.

Comment: you mean [stuff like this?](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Karplus_Strong_Algorithm.html)

Comment: I think yes, but more on a higher front first not pretty sure, but this stuff is also welcome

Comment: What DAW are you using? I teach music production in a high school in toronto and when I teach synthesis (which is what you seem to want to learn) I start my students off with a really simple synth. We use Logic Pro X. I would also suggest that you watch some videos on YouTube for the synth you're interested in learning. Granted, not all videos are informative, but there's a lot of great info out there.